# Rewrite rule (if index.html do nothing) for .htaccess

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, symfony

Im trying the find a rule that says: "if index.html part of url then do nothing"

**Routes**

localhost/rest/token <== Symfony REST backend

localhost/index.html/dashboard <== AngularjS frontend

**.htaccess**

```
    DirectoryIndex app.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value memory_limit 1024M
        php_value max_execution_time 600
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin

        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
        RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
        RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]

        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]


    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_alias.c>
            RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of your htaccess, put the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule index\.html - [L]
```

This will exclude the index.html from your all rewriteRules.